# Symfony2 form methods diffrent in Prod and Dev version

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have problem with my project.
My problem exist when I try to delete some data from entity. My controller was generated with Sesio generator. Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Deletes
 * @Route("/{id}/delete", name="delete")
 * @Method({"DELETE"})
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, Task $task) {

    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($task);
    $form->handleRequest($request);


    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($task);
        $em->flush();
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice_success', 'Success');
    } else {
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice_error', 'NO DELETE');
    }
    return $this->redirectToRoute('task');
}

/**
 * Creates a form to delete.
 */
private function createDeleteForm(Task $task) {
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
                    ->setAction($this->generateUrl('delete', array('id' => $task->getId())))

                    ->add('submit', \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Delete'))
                    ->getForm()
    ;
}
```

I have to tell you that this code work nice on DEV (app_dev.php) but It isn't working in PROD version.

I try to solve that problem and I have tried to change form method to POST and it work property od PROD and DEV. It look like DELETE method doesnt work in PROD version.

Someone have similar problem?

Comment: When you access your app in prod mode, you need to clear the cache for that environment: `$ php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`. Also you may need to set the privileges for `var/cache`, `var/logs`, and `var/sessions` directories: `$ sudo chmod 777 -R var/cache var/logs/ var/sessions` before and after you use the `cache:clear` console command. Then give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the AppCache, the kernel will ignore the `_method` parameter added for DELETE method.

To solve the problem in your `web/app.php` call `Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();` before creating the Request object:

```
...
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();// <-- add this line
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
...
```

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/action_method.html and http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#configuration-framework-http-method-override